# Is there a Cluster convex hull implementation in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, convex-hull, clustering

In this leaflet [example](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-convexhull.html). When hovered over a cluster marker, it shows the bounding area of the clustered features which is known as convex hull.

Is there a way to reproduce it with OpenLayers?

Comment: The example is impressive, but I'm afraid there's no such tool available in openlayers. You have to implement the algorithm by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who ends up here, there is an OL extension which mimics the same functionality as Leaflet. https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext

For demo example see: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/geom/map.convexhull.html

Comment: `ol-ext` extension from example does not work in IE11, since it uses ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no tools yet for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Computing a Convex Hull is possible in OpenLayers by using the external JSTS library.
Although I haven't tried its implementation for convex hull, I have used it to create buffer/union etc.

For more please go to [this url](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.algorithm.ConvexHull.html) also [here](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL210/JSTS_Example/jsts_example.asp) you will find its implementation.